# D3.js JSON data to line-graph

Tags: typescript, d3.js

the reason i switched to this graph from a previous one is because i need the responsiveness of this example [here](https://bl.ocks.org/josiahdavis/raw/7a02e811360ff00c4eef/). Its source-code can be found here: [here](https://bl.ocks.org/josiahdavis/7a02e811360ff00c4eef#index.html).

However, i seem to be unable to input data into this graph, i'm not sure what i'm doing wrong. In my paths' `d` i get a bunch of MNaN's which would indicate that i'm not passing along the data correctly (its most likely not a seen as a number and therefore d3's path-generator throws out these random values at the first error (which is good in this case, because the first number is invalid))...

`Error: <path> attribute d: Expected number, "MNaN,-552LNaN,-60…".`

My best quess as of now to what is causing the errors is that `d3.extent` doesn't understand what i'm feeding it.

My data object looks something like this:

```
[{
    "name": "Data1",
    "data" :
    {
    "resultset": [

        [
            1.42,
            "2018-09-18 00:00:00"
        ],
        [
            1.92,
            "2018-09-18 01:00:00"
        ],
        [
            1.32,
            "2018-09-18 10:33:35"
        ],
        [
            0.00,
            "2018-09-18 10:43:35"
        ]    
    ],
    "metadata": [
        {}
    ],
    "totalrows": 8
}}]
```

Some of you may wonder where the data is coming from, so i'll post this component-snippet:

```
export class MachineGraphComponent implements AfterViewInit, OnInit, OnDestroy {

    eventListeners: Function[] = [];
    machines: GraphData[];
    static componentCount: number = 0;
    //graph settings

    @Input() datasources: { name: any, data: PentahoResponse[] }[]; //Here
    @Input() enableAxisX = 0;
    @Input() enableAxisY = 0;
```

My code (in NgAfterViewInit):

```
var datasources = this.datasources;
var graphSettings = {
    enableAxisX: this.enableAxisX,
    enableAxisY: this.enableAxisY
}

var currentId = this.thisId;
var drawGraph = function (datasources) {

    $('#chart' + currentId + '.chart').empty();

    // Define margins
    var margin = { top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 20 },
        width = parseInt(d3.select('#chart' + currentId + '.chart').style("width")) - margin.left - margin.right,
        height = parseInt(d3.select('#chart' + currentId + '.chart').style("height")) - margin.top - margin.bottom;

    // Define date parser
    var parseDate = d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S").parse;
    //I have tried this one in extent, like in the example linked above ^
    // Define scales
    var xScale = d3.time.scale().range([0, width]);
    var yScale = d3.scale.linear().range([height, 0]);
    var color = d3.scale.ordinal()
        .range(["#8c510a", "#dfc27d", "#35978f"]);

    // Define axes
    var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(xScale).orient("bottom");
    var yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(yScale).orient("left");


    // Define lines
    var line = d3.svg.line().interpolate("basis")
        .x(function (d) { return xScale(d["date"]); })
        .y(function (d) { return yScale(d["value"]); });

    // Define svg canvas
    var svg = d3.select('#chart' + currentId + '.chart').append('svg')
        .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
        .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
        .append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");


    // Read in data
    var datasource: {
        actualValues: any,
        date: string
    }[] = [];
    datasources.forEach(source => {
        source.data.resultset.forEach(data => {
            datasource.push({
                actualValues: data[0],
                date: data[1]
            });
        });
    });
    // Format the data field
    // var data = datasource.slice(); //should i use this?
    var format = d3.time.format("%b %e %Y");
    var dateFn = function (d) {

        return format.parse(d.date);
    };
    // tried to create a dateparser, but didnt solve the problem. 

    // Set the color domain equal to the three product categories
    datasource.forEach(x => {
        x.date = dateFn(x);
    });

    var DatasourceNames = d3.keys(datasources.map(function (d) {
        return d.name;
    }));
    // console.log(datasources.map(function(d){console.log("dwadwa",d.name); return d.name;}));
    color.domain(DatasourceNames);

    var values = DatasourceNames.map(function (category) {
        // console.log("here: ",datasources[category].data.resultset);
        return {
            category: category,
            datapoints: datasource.map(function (d) {
                return {
                    value: d.actualValues,
                    date: d.date
                }
            })
        }
    })

    // Set the domain of the axes
    xScale.domain(d3.extent(datasource, function (d) { return d; }));
    yScale.domain([0.25, 0.5]);

    // Place the axes on the chart
    svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "x axis")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
        .style("opacity", graphSettings.enableAxisX)
        .call(xAxis);

    svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "y axis")
        .style("opacity", graphSettings.enableAxisY)
        .call(yAxis)
        .append("text")
        .attr("class", "label")
        .attr("y", 6)
        .attr("dy", ".71em")
        .attr("dx", ".71em")
        .style("text-anchor", "beginning")
        .text("Product Concentration");

    var products = svg.selectAll(".category")
        .data(values)
        .enter().append("g")
        .attr("class", "category");

    products.append("path")
        .attr("class", "line")
        .attr("d", function (d) { console.log(d.datapoints); return line(d.datapoints); })
        .style("stroke", function (d) { return color(d.category); });

    // console.log(JSON.stringify(d3.values(values), null, 2)) // to view the structure
    // console.log(values.map(function()))

    // Define responsive behavior
    var resize = function () {
        for (var i = 0; i < MachineGraphComponent.componentCount; i++) {

            var svg = d3.select('#chart' + i + '.chart');

            var width = parseInt(d3.select('#chart' + i + '.chart').style("width")) - margin.left - margin.right,
                height = parseInt(d3.select('#chart' + i + '.chart').style("height")) - margin.top - margin.bottom;

            // console.log(i, MachineGraphComponent.componentCount);
            // Update the range of the scale with new width/height
            xScale.range([0, width]);
            yScale.range([height, 0]);

            // Update the axis and text with the new scale
            svg.select('.x.axis')
                .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
                .call(xAxis);

            svg.select('.y.axis')
                .call(yAxis);

            // Force D3 to recalculate and update the line
            svg.selectAll('.line')
                .attr("d", function (d) { return line(d.datapoints); });

            // Update the tick marks
            xAxis.ticks(Math.max(width / 75, 2));
            yAxis.ticks(Math.max(height / 50, 2));
        }
    };

    // Call the resize function whenever a resize event occurs
    d3.select(window).on('resize', resize);

    // Call the resize function
    resize();
};
(function () {
    drawGraph(datasources);
    // drawGraph(dataObj2);
})();
```

When trying to add the lines:

```
    products.append("path")
        .attr("class", "line")
        .attr("d", function (d) { console.log(d.datapoints); return line(d.datapoints); })
        .style("stroke", function (d) { return color(d.category); });
```

this console log give me this:

[image]

If i need to clarify or elabore on something, please let me know.

Comment: The specifier in your parser is wrong. It should be: `var parseDate = d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S").parse;`.

Comment: Oh, yeah, i've been trying to mess around with different parameters and changing my data back and forward. Forgot to change it back, unfortunately, it doesn't give me anything: When printing the arrays out, i get correct values. I'll add them to the question so you can see.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado updated the question with more information

Comment: I'm not debugging your code, I'm just pointing out the first thing wrong that I noticed. Also, the domain doesn't seem to be correct: `xScale.domain(d3.extent(datasource, function (d) { return d; }));`. It should be `d.date` or any other key you're using for the dates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yep, `D3.extent()` does not understand what you are feeding it. I would suggest instead just passing the min and max directly.  The min and max date are hiding two levels deep in your data structure, so you need to go through two levels of array to find them. I apply your time transformation to the original data structure first, so we can get the right output from the D3.min command. Same goes for max

```
//start by cleaning the date in your data
// the original data structure will naow have a nice D3 date.
var TimeFormatter = d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S");
datasources.forEach(source => {
  source.data.resultset.forEach(data => {
    data[1] = TimeFormatter.parse(data[1]);
  });   
});

//find the overall min of all lines and overall max of all limes by enumerating the datasources, then the data in each data source. I'm mapping the time data[1] to the d3.min or d3.max function.
var XoverallMin = d3.min(datasources, function(ds) { return d3.min(ds.data.resultset, function(data){return data[1]}) });
var XoverallMax = d3.max(datasources, function(ds) { return d3.max(ds.data.resultset, function(data){return data[1]}) });


  //once we've found the min and max then setting the domain of the xScale is easy. :-)
     // Set the domain of the axes
      var xScale = d3.time.scale()
                        .range([0, 200])
                        .domain([XoverallMin,XoverallMax]);
```

You are also mapping all your `resultset` into one big `datasource` then applying that same set of data (which combines all the data) to each unique data source name. If instead you make one object per datasource this might help.

```
   // you had only one datasource total, 
    // i changed it so you have a datasource within each of the sources
    datasources.forEach(source => {
        source.datasource = Array();

        source.data.resultset.forEach(data => {
            source.datasource.push({
                value: data[0],
                date: data[1]
            });   
        });

   });

   // ... later in the code,
   // when you create your values object, the data will be separated by  
   //  data source.
    var values = datasources.map(function (source) {
        return {
            category: source.name,
        datapoints: source.datasource //the new object we made and added to
                                      // each source above
        };
      });
```

This s not a total solution, the overall structure has many bugs, but it should get you over some specific hurdles.

Comment: can't use `source.datasource : {` like that. gives me errors :/.

Comment: @Joel - Yeah, sorry, I fixed the example.  I did that after coding for 10 hours so I was a little wacky, I should have tested it first.  :-)

Comment: @Joel - I went in and wrote some code as well to help you determine min and max date.  having those will make setting the domain easier and avoid using `.extent()`.